# How to use ng-options inside Angular 1.5 component?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-components

I have Angular 1.5 component which have to contain a select dropdown with ng-options. This select has to be rendered into different controller's views and in each view a different array of values would be passed into the component.  
But I am not sure how to pass this array of values from a particular view to the component. So, lets say I have the following component, where arrayType would be the binding to the array of values and options would be the binding to the ng-options:

**app.test.component.js**

```
(function() {
angular
    .module('Testcomponent')
    .component('testSelector', {
        controller: TestSelector,
        templateUrl: 'test-selector.html',
        bindings: {
            model: '=',
            form: '<',
            name:'@',
            arrayType: '<',
            options: '='
        }
    });
  function TestSelector() {
    var vm = this;
  }

})();
```

And the html of the component looks like this:

**app.test.component.html**

```
<div>
    <select class="select-form" 
      name="{{vm.name}}"
      arrayType="{{vm.arrayType}}"
      ng-model="vm.model" 
      ng-options="arrayType.value as arrayType.name for arrayType in 
      arrayType">
    </select>
</div>
```

And the in the view of the controller I am using the component like so:
**app.test.controller.js**

```
   <test-selector
        model="vm.something"
        form="vm.TestForm" 
        name="Test Name"
        array-type="vm.specificForTheControllerArray"
        options="What options should I use here?">
    </test-selector>
```

How can I bind the ng-options from the component to be rendered in the view of the controller depending on the specific for each view arrayType?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would just have a comment here, that it is not best practice to use two way binding in a component definition.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, I should think of different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to refer to `$ctrl` or whatever you've specified in the `controllerAs` option in order to access the controller's bindings, in this case: `$ctrl.arrayType`. Also, give a more consistent name for the array item. Try something like this:

```
<select ...
    ng-options="type.value as type.name for type in $ctrl.arrayType">
```

Comment: Thank you! That was what I've missed - to refer to the controller.